# JavaSript trato de hacer una funcion que deshabilite botones repetidos por un ciclo for

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap

Esta es un archivo de prueba donde quiero implementar la siguiente funcionalidad a como la describo pero un otra appweb donde hay una tabla con un foreach para mostrar datos de una base de datos de mysql

la idea es que al presionar el btn1 de la fila 0  me desactive el btn2 y btn3 de la fila 0
al presionar el btn1 de la fila 1  me desactive el btn2 y btn3 de la fila 1, pero el btn1 de la fila 0 desactiva el btn2 y btn3 de la fila 0 Y el btn1 de la fila 1 desactiva el btn2 y btn3 de la fila 0.

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <br>
    <br>

<?php for ($i=0; $i <3 ; $i++) { ?>
  <label>fila <?php echo $i; ?></label>
    <button id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="deshabilitar2(),deshabilitar()">btn1</button>
    <button id="btn2" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">btn2</button>
    <button id="btn3" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">btn3</button>
    <br>
  <?php }  ?>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="desc.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-IDwe1+LCz02ROU9k972gdyvl+AESN10+x7tBKgc9I5HFtuNz0wWnPclzo6p9vxnk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**El archivo de javascript**

```
var btn1=document.getElementById('btn1'),
btn2=document.getElementById('btn2'),
btn3=document.getElementById('btn3'),
contador=0;

contador2=0;

function deshabilitar() {
    if (contador==0) {
        document.getElementById('btn2').disabled=true;
        contador=1;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('btn2').disabled=false;
        contador=0;
    }
}

function deshabilitar2() {
    if (contador2==0) {
        document.getElementById('btn3').disabled=true;
        contador2=1;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('btn3').disabled=false;
        contador2=0;
    }
}
```

[este es el resultado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqwrD.png)

bueno como dije antes no importa cual btn1 presione solo se desactivan los btn2 y btn3 de la fila 0 y no la de sus respectivas filas

Comment: Estas repitiendo los id y solo te coge el primero que encuentra, y en **HTML nunca deben repetirse los id**.  Aprovecha que estas en un bucle y usa la $i para que los id sean todos únicos, y luego le pasas la $i a la función y que la interprete bien para deshabilitar esos botones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso pasa porque repites tus ID's, los ID's deben ser unicos por página y al repetirlos los navegadores pueden operar como quieran, donde generalmente toman el primero elemento encontrado.

Lo más fácil es concatenar al ID el número de fila
(Pon ojo en los ID de los botones y en los eventos, donde le pasaremos en número de fila)

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i <3 ; $i++) { ?>
  <label>fila <?php echo $i; ?></label>
    <button id="btn1_<?php echo $i ?>" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="deshabilitar2(<?php echo $i ?>),deshabilitar(<?php echo $i ?>")">btn1</button>
    <button id="btn2_<?php echo $i ?>" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">btn2</button>
    <button id="btn3_<?php echo $i ?>" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">btn3</button>
    <br>
  <?php }  ?>
```

Luego en javascript

```
function deshabilitar(num) {
    if (contador==0) {
        document.getElementById('btn2_' + num).disabled=true;
        contador=1;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('btn2_' + num).disabled=false;
        contador=0;
    }
}

function deshabilitar2(num) {
    if (contador2==0) {
        document.getElementById('btn3_' + num).disabled=true;
        contador2=1;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('btn3_' + num).disabled=false;
        contador2=0;
    }
}
```

**Update**

Sobre tu pregunta en los comentarios:

Lo primero es tener claro que hace PHP, el cual crea (imprime) un documento. Generalmente el documento es HTML e imprime elementos también HTML, pero en realidad puedes crear javascript, CSS o incluso otro tipo de documentos.

Por ejemplo este código

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i <3 ; $i++) { ?>
    <button onclick="deshabilitar(<?php echo $i ?>)"></button> 
<?php }  ?>
```

Se transforma en

```
<button onclick="deshabilitar(0)"></button> 
<button onclick="deshabilitar(1)"></button> 
<button onclick="deshabilitar(2)"></button>
```

Esto es lo que le llega a tu navegador, en donde ya empieza a operar lo Javascript y por lo cual al presionar un botón llama a la función "deshabilitar" enviándole un parámetro. Cual parámetro?? el que tiene fijo el botón correspondiente

Lo que tu comentas que tenias

```
document.getElementById('btn2<?php echo $i ?>' ).disabled=true;
```

No es que no se pueda hacer, solo que bajo tu lógica y tu necesidad no te servía de mucho, porque al salir de PHP esto queda fijo y tu necesitabas que sea dinámico, que para un botón de una fila X hiciera algo a otros botones de la misma fila, donde X es la variable de la fila. Ese dinamismo es el que solucionas al pasar la variable por parámetro.

Comment: En verdad muchas muchas gracias llevaba bastante tiempo  tratando de solucionar eso... de echo mi idea era hacerlo asi adjuntar en el id del boton mas un variable en php pero lo pasaba asi document.getElementById('btn2<?php echo $i ?>' ).disabled=true; 
pero nunca funciono, podrias explicarme mas acerca de como funciona poner la variable en la funcion del onclick muchas gracias de todas formas

Answer (score 1):

Tal como ya te han dicho, y también te habia comentado, repites ids.

Pero en tu javascript casi que repites la función, pues son muy parecidas ambas, que además dan errores porque `contador` y `contador2` se hacen un lio cuando pulsas diversos botones varias veces, así que he aplicado estos cambios a mi solución, ejecutándo sólo una función que puede contener tantos botones como quieras, pasándoselos en un array:

```php
<?php for ($i=0; $i <3 ; $i++) { ?>
  <label>fila <?=$i?></label>
    <button id="btn1_<?=$i?>" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="deshabilitar([2,3],<?=$i?>)">btn1</button>
    <button id="btn2_<?=$i?>" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">btn2</button>
    <button id="btn3_<?=$i?>" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">btn3</button>
    <br>
  <?php }  ?>
```

Y luego quita todo tu javascript y pon esto:

```javascript
function deshabilitar(arr, i) {
  arr.forEach( function(num) {
    boton = document.getElementById('btn' + num + '_' + i)
    if (boton.disabled) {
      boton.disabled = false;
    } else {
      boton.disabled = true;
    }
    }
  )
}
```

Aquí un ejemplo funcional de como debería quedar con el php ya interpretado (he quitado el popper.min.js y el boostrap.min.js porque el bootstrap.bundle.min.js ya contiene ambos y estabas cargándolos varias veces):

```js
function deshabilitar(arr, i) {
  arr.forEach(function(num) {
    boton = document.getElementById('btn' + num + '_' + i)
    if (boton.disabled) {
      boton.disabled = false;
    } else {
      boton.disabled = true;
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <label>fila 1</label>
  <button id="btn1_1" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="deshabilitar([2,3],1)">btn1</button>
  <button id="btn2_1" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">btn2</button>
  <button id="btn3_1" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">btn3</button>
  <br>
  <label>fila 2</label>
  <button id="btn1_2" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="deshabilitar([2,3],2)">btn1</button>
  <button id="btn2_2" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">btn2</button>
  <button id="btn3_2" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">btn3</button>
  <br>
  <label>fila 3</label>
  <button id="btn1_3" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="deshabilitar([2,3],3)">btn1</button>
  <button id="btn2_3" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">btn2</button>
  <button id="btn3_3" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">btn3</button>
  <br>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="desc.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: muchas gracias  en verdad esta increible asi, la verdad no se practicamente nada de javascrip esta muy padre tu solucion